# Convert netbeans project with embedded databases to a stand alone java program

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a very complex java program written with net beans 7.1.  It consists of 1 .java file that has a main(), and over 25 supporting .java files (most used for routines inside of tabs).  In addition there are 15 different databases (embedded) associated with it.  The program is virtually complete, and I need to export this project to a stand-alone Java application (including the databases) that is completely independent of net beans and may run on any system that supports Java.  This is intended to be a desktop application, not a web based program.

I am a fairly experienced programmer, however this is my first attempt in writing programs in java.  If I could get links that may provide step-by-step procedures and/or examples that would be the most help.  Or even better if there are software apps out there that would take the net beans code and generate a executable program.

Any assistance or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you build your project a .jar file will be placed inside your "dist" folder. If you cant doulbe click your jar file and have it run look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html to learn the basics of the manifest file and how it works. Also you can convert jar files to exe files using some 3rd party programs that are widely avalible you can look it up on Google.

Answer (score 1):

You must try out a free software named 'JavaExe' which can convert jarfiles (or java classes) 
directly into .exe
Vikrant
(India)

Answer (score 0):

When you build it, the stand-alone program should appear in a "dist" folder.

If you have problems with running this program, I am afraid, you have to write your own ant/maven script.

Comment: I have tried this....  I am getting an error saying that 2 of the databases do not exist.  Since that these two necessary databases weren't found,  all other remaining data is not loaded.

Comment: Well this is something you should say us in the first place when asking question :).