# How to save as a stand-alone project in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, project

I'm referring to NetBeans only (I'm using 7.4):

Is there a way to save the current project (someone's working on) as a new *stand-alone* project for backup purposes?
I want to be able to take the newly saved project on a USB drive and work on another PC and to have multiple projects to choose from, to load on the stick.

I tried right clicking on the project in projects pane and copy. It went fine except for it didn't copy the entire project folder and most of all -- it had the external library dependencies messed up and had to manually copy them into the new project folder and link to each of them.
I also tried exporting the project as zip and it behaves the same.
I don't want to have my project on the web -- that's why I didn't go with repositories.
I also read [Convert netbeans project with embedded databases to a stand alone java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375044/convert-netbeans-project-with-embedded-databases-to-a-stand-alone-java-program) but this implies that all files are error free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Netbeans for this, go directly to the project location in your hard drive and do a ctrl + c and then ctrl + v in the desired destination.

This will copy everything, configuration files, property files, external libraries that have been added to the project.

In the case of a development database, you have to make a dump of it and copy the dump file to you USB. It should no t be too hard to keep a development copy that you can import wherever you go.

If you ask me, doing this is asking for trouble. Use a repository, if the reason not too is:

> I don't want to have the project publicly available.

Then you are taking the wrong approach to the problem. Find a source code version control service that allows you to have private projects. There are cost based and free offerings that you can pick from.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate when someone gives a requested solution even if he/she is not convinced of the asker's approach.  I also thank you for the _value_ of your solution (manual copy), it's the best way for me; I tried it and it seem to work without issues (I expected NB to complain about mismatches/references)